# How to display multiple notification at the same time

Tags: android, notifications

Im developing an Android application that will generate notifications and the application is working fine, but the problem is that when the phone receive a notification and receive another notification, the later notification hide the first. I want as the application receive many notifications theses all notification should be displayed not only one (the later) please how could i do that?

Here is the code that handle the notification.

```
  private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Activity_SplashScreen.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass different `notification id` for each `Notification` . If you pass same id (i.e., 0 in your case), the existed `notification` will be updated with the new data

So change this:

```
  notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

to , e.g., Set some unique id  int notificationId = 0x10;

```
notificationManager.notify(++notificationId, notification);
```

**ID** -  If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line `notificationManager.notify(0, notification);` the `0` is the notification ID.  If you want to show multiple notifications, you need to change that ID.  All notifications with the same ID overwrite each other.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html